# when select coordinate point show the selected space in canvas

Tags: html, canvas, coordinate

when click on coordinate canvas this show a point, when click again show again point, but I want to delete previous point when next is selected(click), 
please help me to resolve, I am also trying to do this with jquery but that is also not suitable, I am also trying to use "clearRec" method but it 
remove coordinate graph also

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        #cordCanvas {
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div id=container>
        <canvas id="cordCanvas" width="150" height="150" onclick="draw(event); showCoords(event);"></canvas>
    </div>

    <p id='showCoords'></p>
    <script>
        var cordCanvas = document.getElementById("cordCanvas");
        var context = cordCanvas.getContext("2d");

        function draw(e) {
            var pos = getMousePos(cordCanvas, e);
            posx = pos.x;
            posy = pos.y;
            // context.clearRect(0, 0, cordCanvas.width, cordCanvas.height);

            context.fillStyle = "#000000";
            context.beginPath();
            context.arc(posx, posy, 2, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
            context.fill();

        }

        function getMousePos(cordCanvas, evt) {
            var rect = cordCanvas.getBoundingClientRect();
            return {
                x: evt.clientX - rect.left,
                y: evt.clientY - rect.top
            };
        }
        window.onload = drawCord;
        function drawCord() {
            var cordCanvas = document.getElementById('cordCanvas');
            if (cordCanvas.getContext) {
                var context = cordCanvas.getContext('2d');

                for (var x = 0.5; x < 150; x += 15) {
                    context.moveTo(x, 0);
                    context.lineTo(x, 150);
                }

                for (var y = 0.5; y < 150; y += 15) {
                    context.moveTo(0, y);
                    context.lineTo(150, y);
                }

                context.strokeStyle = '#00abff';
                context.stroke();
            }
        }

        function showCoords(event) {
            var x = event.clientX - 10;
            var y = event.clientY - 10;
            var coords = "X coordinates: " + x + ", Y coordinates: " + y;
            document.getElementById('showCoords').innerHTML = coords;

        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```